# Why do these two ways of thinking about current seem to be contradictory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, poynting-vector

I was studying for my electrodynamics exam and came across two questions which seemed to require conflicting models of how power is transferred in a current carrying wire.

**The first question**:

A straight cylindrical wire of length $L$, radius $R$ and cross-sectional area $A$ has a potential difference of $V$ across it and a current $I$ flowing through it. Find the Poynting vector and show that the energy flowing into the wire per unit time is indeed $IV$ as predicted by the Joule heating law.

**The Answer**:

Orient the wire along the z-axis. Work in cylindrical coordinates (r,$\phi$,z). If we assume there is uniform current through the wire then

$\vec{J} = \frac{I}{A}\hat{z}$

So $\vec{E} = \frac{I}{\sigma A}\hat{z}$  where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the wire.

We use Ampere's law for the magnetic field on the boundary.

$\int \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_{0}I$

Because of spherical symmetry this reduces to the familar

$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi R}\hat{\phi}$

So the Poynting vector is given by

$\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}\vec{E}\times\vec{B} = \frac{I^2}{2\pi R \sigma A}\hat{z}\times\hat{\phi} = -\frac{I^2}{2\pi R \sigma A}\hat{r}$

The Poynting vector has no component in the z direction so we get

$\int \vec{S}\cdot d\vec{A} = -|S|(2\pi R L) = -\frac{L I^2}{\sigma A}$

But this is energy out of the wire so to find the energy into the wire we drop the negative sign.

$ P = \frac{L I^2}{\sigma A}$

We identify this as the product of the resistance with the current squared and using Ohm's law it becomes

$P = IV$

**All good and well** but then this next question came up.

**The second question**

An infinite cylindrical current carrying wire of radius R has a charge density $\rho$ moving in the positive z direction at speed v. Find the electric and magnetic fields generated as well as the Poynting vector at the point (R,0,0).

**The answer**

The electric field is simple. We create a cylindrical Gaussian surface of length L around the surface of the wire. Since the electric field at the surface is generated by the charge within it will point outwards so

$\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A} = Q/\epsilon_{0} = \rho \pi R^2 L/\epsilon_{0}$

$E(2\pi R L) = \rho \pi R^2 L/\epsilon_{0}$

from which we get

$\vec{E} = \frac{\rho R}{\epsilon_{0}} \hat{r}$

Now for the magnetic field.

Standard Amperian loop around surface, bla bla bla...

$\int \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} =\mu_{0}I$

To work out the current we imagine the total charge passing a point in time T. We find that the total charge is $\rho$ times the volume of the cylinder with radius R and height vT. So

$Q= \rho \pi R^2vT$.

So

$I = \rho \pi R^2 v$

Then $\int \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} =\mu_{0}\rho \pi R^2 v$

$2\pi R B =\mu_{0}\rho \pi R^2 v$

$ \vec{B} = \frac{\mu_{0}\rho R}{2}\hat{\phi}$

Finally the Poynting vector:

$\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}\vec{E}\times\vec{B} = \frac{\rho^2 R^2}{2\epsilon_{0}} \hat{r}\times\hat{\phi} = \frac{\rho^2 R^2}{2\epsilon_{0}} \hat{z}$

**Ok sorry for boring you with that** but now here is my confusion. In the one case the electric field is in the z direction causing the current to flow. The Poynting vector is radially inwards. In the other the electric field is radially outwards and the energy flows along the wire. In the second case, if the electric field is indeed radially outwards, what is actually pushing the charge along the wire? This actually relates to a general concept I don't really understand. If charge density is $\rho$ and current is $\rho v$ then are these different charge densities? Because of course you can have a neutral wire with current so they can't be the same. Yet in the second question that seemed to be the case. My suspicion is that the problem lies with the second question, not the first. Also, as a small aside, in the first question energy is flowing radially into the wire. But shouldn't the wire be radiating energy? Wires get hot and radiate heat. They don't suck in energy from somewhere else. Thanks for bearing with me. Regards,

Comment: Hi Jarah Fluxman, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I think you've got the seed of a good question here, but perhaps it could be organized better. How about you start your post by giving a _brief_ summary of each of the two physical situations, and then put your conceptual question (the stuff from the last paragraph, more or less) right after that? Then afterwards you can put the full question and answer. That way people don't have to read (or scroll) so far to get to what you're actually asking.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just going to bed now but I should be able to change it in a day or two

Comment: The wire is not charged and there is no outward field.